# CSS3 webkit-transition using multiple properties of a div and multiple webkit-transition-delay

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to transform a div by sliding it 200px to the right and then reducing it's scale by half. I'd like to slide THEN reduce the scale of the div, however I can't get the 2 transforms to operate independently, it slides and rescales at the same time. I thought that webkit-transition-delay would fix this problem, but it only ever applies the last delay specified (in this example 2s) to both transforms. Any thoughts?

```
.example-3-transform {
            -webkit-transform: translate(200px) scale(0.5);
            -webkit-transition-property: webkit-transition-translate, webkit-transition-scale;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out, ease-in-out; 
            -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a keyframe for that:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myanim {

  50% { -webkit-transform: translate(200px) scale(1) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(200px) scale(0.5) }

}

.example-3-transform { -webkit-animation: myanim 5s 1 ease-in-out forwards }
```

the parameters are:

- 5s: duration of animation
- 1: repetition
- ease-in-out: timing algorithm, can also be linear, ease-in, ease-out, or cubic-bezier
  with custom parameters
- forwards: will keep the style in desired
  state after animation finishes.

Comment: Thanks, this created the desired effect!